# Simple Image Browser in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Simple Image browser plugin from ckeditor(http://ckeditor.com/addon/simple-image-browser) with asp.net mvc4.

I tried to use it as in its documentation but its still not working.

My script is:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'simple-image-browser';
CKEDITOR.config.simpleImageBrowserURL = "/Home/SomeActionMethod";
```

and my controller is:

```
public JsonResult SomeActionMethod(){
var items = new[] {
                  new {url = "http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"}, 
                  new {url = "http://localhost:63220/Images/heroAccent.png"}};
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In console it throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Do somebody has experience of using it???

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Is there an error, or a message or is the image list empty?

Comment: In console it throws an error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: Can you check whether the url you're trying to reach can be reached and the output of the page is correct?

Comment: url is for image and i think it is correct one. When I enter this url in browser it shows image.. so i suppose it is correct one.

Comment: I meant the `/Home/SomeActionMethod`-url. This should show an array, not an imag. Right?

Comment: Yes I debug it with debug point and its fine.. and the json response also seems to be fine.. When i print it in console it shows : [Object, Object] ,Which seems to be in fine format of the expected response as in documentation: http://ckeditor.com/addon/simple-image-browser

Answer (score 0):

@Prakash Rai - ITH:
Open config.js file you will see the code:

```
return console.log(a),b=$.parseJSON(a)
```

If you return JSON already you should replace

```
return console.log(a),b=a
```